# Employee schedule program

Tags: scheduling

I look for a program that can take a list of people and give each one of them a placing in a schedule.

The program should have the ability to follow restrictions:

- If an employee can't do a shift in a specific day, the program won't set him on this day.
- If an employee be set to a shift that the scheduler, set as highly rewarding, the number of shifts that he would do in a given month will be reduced accordingly.
- The software should work without internet.

The program should be runnable on Windows 7.
The program should output an excel or a table file.
The GUI should be comfortable.
About corrections, I'll be able to edit the excel files.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Mind to [edit] your question and add what OS it should run on? Also, you might have some requirements according to the GUI or the "output produced" – some of them probably optional. Should it e.g. show the shifts in a calendar, or in a [Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart)? Do you want to be able to do manual corrections (e.g. if an employee suddenly gets ill)?

Comment: Would [ABC Roster](http://www.abc-roster.com/) be a suitable tool?