# Employee scheduling app

Tags: scheduling

I want to find an app which when I give it the days that I want my employees to work, it solves the days itself.

For example, if I want my employee to work two days a week and he gave me three free days, I want the program to consider other people's days too and then give me the final schedule (I want this on each day too). Also all the weeks are similar, so I just have to schedule for one week.

This app can be on Android and Windows, and it's OK if it's not free.

Comment: Maybe [this discussion](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21467/employee-schedule-program) is relevant, then.